# Tomcat versions aren't starting

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-7, configuration

Just downloaded Tomcat 7.0.26, unzipped it, ran the `startup.bat` file and it failed with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)         
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)       
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)       
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)        
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:336)
    ... 1 more
```

A co-worker recommended I try using an older/more stable version of Tomcat. He's running 6.0.35, so I decided to try that.

I did the same exact thing with 6.0.35...and the same thing is happening to me...

What is going on here?!?!  I see in `bin/tomcat-juli.jar` that the LogFactory is there (both versions)...

**Edit**:

Here are the values for several environment variables:

- CLASSPATH: `.;C:\Users\<myUser>\Desktop\jars\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip`
- JAVA_HOME: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25`

These don't seem to add up!?! If I'm reading this correctly, doesn't it say that the CLASSPATH thinks I'm using `jre6`, but that Java Home is set to `jdk1.6.0_25`?

Comment: LogFactory is a class of Apache commons logging. Have you deployed anything in your tomcat? (Have you copied a war file in your webapps folder)?

Comment: Check your CLASSPATH env variable for any old logging libs.

Comment: Yes I have a WAR in the webapps directory, but Tomcat starts up and dies within 2 seconds of running startup.bat. CLASSPATH doesn't have anything in it.

Comment: Get rid of any manually added JAR files inside JRE/lib and JRE/lib/ext folders and **never** touch them unless you really understand what you're doing.

Comment: Good thought (and thanks!) - but I've never added JARs to those directories.

Comment: The symptoms tells otherwise. At least, your classpath is dirty.

Comment: Balus - please see my edit above - do these env vars mean anything to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that some environment variable is set in your system which is preventing Tomcat from running.

Check:

- CATALINA_HOME
- CATALINA_BASE
- CATALINA_OPTS (for classpath additions)
- JAVA_OPTS (for classpath additions)

and less likely:

- LOGGING_CONFIG
- LOGGING_MANAGER

If any of these environment variables are set, correct or unset them.  My guess is that `CATALINA_HOME` is set to point to a different version of Tomcat on your system.

Comment: Thanks prunge - please see my edit to the original question and let me know if it triggers any thoughts. Thanks again!

Comment: @AdamTannon it might be worth trying to run Tomcat from a command prompt with a clean set of environment variables just to rule this out as a problem.  Before running startup.bat, clear out each of the environment variables mentioned in my initial answer by using `set <VAR NAME>=` for each variable.

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded Tomcat 7.0.26 2 hours ago and its working fine. It looks like you have an old version of commons-logging.jar anywhere in your classpath (path variable, jre versions/lib, etc...).

Comment: Wouldn't the version of commons-logging.jar that Tomcat needs...ship with Tomcat?!?! What am I missing here?

Comment: commons-logging is renamed to private package tomcat-juli.jar. I guess the problem is related to it's autoconfiguration. Maybe check these 5 config steps: [link](http://commons.apache.org/logging/guide.html#Configuration). If this is not working try switching to Log4J or Jul (tomcat docs).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
All I did was to copy all the jar files in [apache-tomcat]/lib directory and all the jar files in [apache-tomcat]/bin to [jdk directory]/jre/lib/ext directory.
This should solved the problem.